# Can you use negative values in the CSS clamp() function?

Tags: css, clamp

I would love to implement fluid letter-spacing using the clamp function in CSS. But as i like my letter spacing tight, i would need to have three negative values in the formula and tried now for hours to figure this one out. Do I have to switch the min and max values, as they are negative?

```
letter-spacing: clamp(-1px, -1vw, -3px);
```

I need to have more space, the smaller the font gets, not in a linear way. Any idea on how this could be achieved would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use probably:

```css
letter-spacing: calc(clamp(-1px, -1vw, -3px)  * -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use negative values in `clamp`.

> Do I have to switch the min and max values, as they are negative?

`clamp` is defined as `clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX)` which is equal `max(MIN, min(VAL, MAX))`. So `MIN` has to be smaller than `MAX`.

So `clamp(-1px, -1vw, -3px)` is wrong because `-1px` is larger than `-3px`.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta turn around those values. As the first one is the minimum value and the last one the maximum. -3px is smaller than -1px. I made the spacing larger so you can see it. But this works totally fine for me.

```css
p {
  letter-spacing: clamp(-30px, -10vw, -10px);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Hello
</p>
```

Comment: hi quentin. thanks for your answer and sorry for the late reply. i have tried your solution but it has the opposite effect of what i am looking for. the clamp works, but the bigger the type gets, the more space it gets. the function seems reversed, as soon as you use negative values...